# JavaScript: Issues with methods and functions in refactored object

Tags: javascript, methods, refactoring, javascript-objects

First time asking!

my refactored methods (methods used to be inside object) are not recognizing their relations to the object anymore... How do I get these to work?

I'm trying to apply a move and accelerate function to this object (car). The move_fn increases the car's position linearly (1, 2, 3, 4... n). The acc_fn increases the car's acceleration exponentially by adding the car's previous speed increase with its current position (30mph + 2 position = 32mph, 32mph + 3 position = 35mph, 35mph + 4 position = 39mph, etc.). Also, function_runner runs both methods simultaneously, which keeps everything commencing in order:

```
var move_fn = function(){
  var prev_position = this.position
  this.position += + 1
  console.log(this.type + " is moving from " + prev_position + " to " + 
  this.position + '.')
}

var spd_fn = function(){
  var prev_speed = this.speed
  console.log(this.position)
  this.speed += this.position
  console.log(this.type + ' is accelerating from ' + prev_speed + ' to ' +
  this.speed + '.' )
}

var function_runner = function(){
  this.move_fn()
  this.acc_fn()
}

var car = {
  type: 'Honda CRV',
  position: 1,
  speed: 30,
  move: move_fn,
  speed: spd_fn,
  fn_run: function_runner
}


car.function_runner()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Car no longer has a method called function_runner, you've assigned it to the fn_run method, so you'd call car.fn_run(). Same thing with move_fn - renamed to move,  and "acc_fn" isn't defined anywhere.

So it'd be:

```
var move_fn = function(){
  var prev_position = this.position
  this.position += + 1
  console.log(this.type + " is moving from " + prev_position + " to " + 
  this.position + '.')
}

var spd_fn = function(){
  var prev_speed = this.speed
  console.log(this.position)
  this.speed += this.position
  console.log(this.type + ' is accelerating from ' + prev_speed + ' to ' +
  this.speed + '.' )
}

var function_runner = function(){
  this.move()
  this.speed()
}

var car = {
  type: 'Honda CRV',
  position: 1,
  speed: 30,
  move: move_fn,
  speed: spd_fn,
  fn_run: function_runner
}

car.fn_run()
```

...although it is a strange way of structuring it.

Comment: I also have two properties named 'speed', which messed things up. With your help and some more tinkering, its working again! Thanks!